# Add text to a cell automatically if another cell is not empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've managed to use scripts to automate a few things on a Google Sheet I'm working on, but can't quite seem to work this one out.

I want to insert the letter **Y** into **Column B** if **Column R isn't empty**.

I tried to follow this one but got a bit confused - [If cell contains a text then add text automatically to another column cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649756/if-cell-contains-a-text-then-add-text-automatically-to-another-column-cell)

I couldn't figure out how to specify the target column (R) or what to put where ???? is to make it 'not empty'

```
function fillColB() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = s.getDataRange().getValues();
  var data_len = data.length;
  for(var i=0; i<data_len; i++) {
    if(data[i][0] == "?????") {
      s.getRange(i+1,2).setValue("Y");
      }
    }
  }
```

Can anyone suggest a script I could add to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only the data from column R, you could use

```
var data = s.getRange("R1:R").getValues();
```

Then to loop over that just like how you're doing.

Testing if the length is 0 should be equivalent to testing if the cell is blank:

```
if(data[i][0].length == 0) {
```

Although a cell set to an empty string ="" would also have length zero, meaning this script would act like it's a blank cell.

Final code:

```
function fillColB() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = s.getRange("R1:R").getValues();
var data_len = data.length;
for(var i=0; i<data_len; i++) {
  if(data[i][0].length == 0) {
    s.getRange(i+1,2).setValue("Y");
  } else {
    s.getRange(i+1,2).setValue("N");
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I popped it into the editor (then tried removing the `} else {
    s.getRange(i+1,2).setValue("N");
  }` to leave the cell blank if there's nothing in R and nothing seems to be happening. I tried adding `function onEdit(event) {` at the beginning to see if it could run automatically, but I think I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Oh, you can use custom triggers to make that happen. Click on the clock-like icon next to the save icon. A box will pop up, and you can specify a function and a type of event. Set the function to `fillColB` and type to `From Spreadsheet` then `On edit`.